# How this letter changes from f to r in address bar

Tags: firefox, security, typography

Recently while i was browsing at [offensive](https://www.offensive-security.com/offsec/say-try-harder/) security website at firefox ,the words 'offensive' appears to be **oRensive** at address bar,Kindly have a look at the below snapshot :

[image]

Note at the address bar,if i type offensive it gets automatically converted into `oRensive`,

I am sure that the website is not redirecting to anywhere,but how could two 'ff' will lead to appear it as **R**

any internal configuration or site was build specifically to be turned into R while typing 'ff'?

Comment: more OS specifics? Also, it is not real R, but rather R-bar or something. Can you copy this character into something that can read Unicode explicitly?

Comment: Does this happen with other sites with "ff" in the url?

Comment: @Paul nope its happening in that one particular website

Comment: Seems like it must be a locale thing.  What region is your machine set to

Comment: Does it do it immediately after entering the "ff" or when you press enter and the page begins to load? Does it do it with all websites with "ff" in them or just this one? As an example try http://offensive.com (placeholder site) and http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/aftereffects.html (ff near the end of the URL).

Comment: @Mokubai it changes after immediately entering 'ff',also it changes only for that particular website,while i tried with adobe site it doesnt change

Comment: Can you copy the URL directly out of the browser and paste it here? The "R" looks like it has a bar above it which could be important, hopefully it copies the replaced letter instead of what you type.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 64-bit, Firefox 44.0 64-bit.